# Air flow through a tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, air

During a discussion, a friend explained to me that the volume of air flowing through a tube could be increased up to the point where the air reached supersonic velocity.  Presumably the pressure difference at each end of the tube would need to be increased for this to be possible up until the velocity became supersonic.

My question is first of all, is this true, then what happens after that velocity is reached?

Comment: The second of your questions would be better placed at SE Engineering site.